# Bad visual behavior with extended GlassFrame

Tags: delphi, api, aero, dwm

I have a major problem which I can't solve.

I'm editing question in order to simplify what really happens:

1. Create blank Delphi application (I've tried this in 2007)
2. In Form constructor (From.Create) type:

   ```
   GlassFrame.Enabled := True;
   GlassFrame.Bottom := 50;
   ```

This should extend Windows Aero theme.

Now try to resize window and you'll notice bad behavior; black part that looks pretty ugly.

Is this Windows bug or?

I've tried the same thing under MS VC, using API calls but results are the same.

Anyway, if it's Windows bug I have to solve it somehow cause I can allow such a bad look in my application.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You haven't posted any code at all, so it's hard to say what the problem might be. You also tagged it `C++` and `Delphi`, but posted code or text that refers to neither of them. Can you edit your question to clarify what language you're using and add code that shows what you're trying to do? Thanks. :)

Comment: You can try this very simple, that is why I didn't put any example:

1) Create new Delphi project
2) On mainform Enable GlassFrame
3) Set Bottom (into GlassFrame section) to let say 50
4) Start and try to resize

Check what happens with background.

I've tried that in D2007, also tried it in some older MS VS but I don't think that it's fixed in new ver but that this is bug caused by Window.

Maybe I wrong and I hope that I wrong cause with this app looks awful!

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Again, **can you edit your question** to provide more information (including the instructions from your comment)? As it is now, it should probably be closed as "not a real question".

Answer (score 0):

`DoubleBuffered := True` fixes the black glitch.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same.. :(

Comment: Are you setting `DoubleBuffered` to `True` on Construction, or when the Form is already visible? As far as I know, you cannot change the `DoubleBuffered` Property when the Form is being displayed.

Comment: I'm setting it in FormCreate. That event should be called in constructor. So before WM_SHOW.

Comment: Another troubleshooting step: have you tried running the same compiled application on other machines to eliminate the possibility of system-specific behaviour?

Comment: Yes, of course. It happens under Vista or Win7 with Aero theme on.